# How can I get the numbers in my table to be centered in the middle instead of at 0.?

Tags: tables

I am making a table for results from a survey. I found a template that is perfect to use. However, the numbers somehow center at 0. and not in the middle of the number. I have tried looking for a command that will fix it, or if any of the commands in my code chunk causes this. Therefore my question is if anyone can tell me how I can fix it. This is my first posted question here so I hope I have provided enough information.
Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Results from the experiment}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{T{1.2}T{1.3}} @{}}
            \toprule
            Type of nudge or incentive  & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Groups}\\
            \cmidrule(l){2-5}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Vaccinated} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Unvaccinated} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
            & {Yes} & {No} & {Yes} & {No} \\
            \toprule
            Q1: Nudging for vaccination & 10 & 0 & 100 & 0 \\
            Q2: Positive incentive of freedom  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            Q3: Positive monetary incentive  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            Q4: Negative incentive of freedom  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            Q5: Negative monetary incentive  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            Q6: Nudging against vaccination  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just use a `c` column, the whole point of the siunitx formatted number columns are to align the numbers so 10 is not centred under 100 but that the units digits are aligned, which is normally what you want for numeric data.

Comment: Thank you! Is it however possible to use the siunitx format in everything else so that only the numbers are centered?

Comment: sorry I do not understand the question, the siunitx tabular columns are only for numeric entries and implement alignment of the digits not centering, but you do not have to use that column type

Comment: Please excuse my unclear question. However, I found the answer further down. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem arises due to using `T{1.2}` and `T{1.3}`. If instead `T{3.0}` and `T{1.0}` are used, the alignment seems nicer (to me).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Results from the experiment}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{T{3.0}T{1.0}} @{}}
            \toprule
            Type of nudge or incentive  & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Groups}\\
            \cmidrule(l){2-5}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Vaccinated} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Unvaccinated} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
            & {Yes} & {No} & {Yes} & {No} \\
            \toprule
            Q1: Nudging for vaccination & 10 & 0 & 100 & 0 \\
            Q2: Positive incentive of freedom  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            Q3: Positive monetary incentive  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            Q4: Negative incentive of freedom  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            Q5: Negative monetary incentive  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            Q6: Nudging against vaccination  & 100 & 0   & 100 & 0 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I normally just use `T{1.0}` that way it is easier to see what is going on.

Comment: That looks really good. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @daleif Sorry, I haven't understood your comment clearly. Are you suggesting to use `T{1.0}`?

Comment: @Imran Yes, `T{3}` is the same as `T{3.0}` but with the latter it is clear that we are leaving no space for decimals.

Comment: @daleif Oh, thanks, got it. Edited accordingly.